# Match and replace words with replace function

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Is there a (supposedly) simple way to get an exact match when using the replace function in SQL Server? (I'm open to other searching possibilities as well, of course).

I have 2 tables. Personal_details and Standrd_name.

In personal_details I have full_name and Standard_full_name.In standrd_name I have name and standard_name.

The logic is I need to match full_name of personal_details to name of standard_name and return standard_name.

example
Standrd_name

| Name | Standard_name |
| --- | --- |
| Count | CT |
| International | INTL |

Personal_details

| full name |
| --- |
| Court |
| Courtney |
| International |
| Internationals |
| Aj International |

The expected result is

| full name | Standard full name |
| --- | --- |
| Court | CT |
| Courtney | Courtney |
| International | INTL |
| Internationals | Internationals |
| AJ International | AJ INTL |

It needs to replace if its an exact match.
I want to have a generic solution for this issue not this case specific.

Comment: SQL server or Snowflake? They are very different!

Comment: I need the solution for both.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried?

Comment: You might not be able to get a common solution

Comment: replace function will not work here for ovious reasons. The code is in client system,which I cant copy to my local.

Comment: I need a generic solution as the standrd table may be modified in future. They may add/delete/change any thing.

Comment: You have so many spelling errors your logic makes no sense. Please go through and correct them

Comment: The question is unclear. There's no string replacement involved here. You're matching two tables on a field. If there's a match, you return the match. If not, you return the original. You can do that with a LEFT JOIN and returning the first non-null value from the two tables. You can use `COALESCE` to return the first non-null field but the way the function behaves in the two databases can differ

Comment: Assuming you *don't* want string replacement, you could try `SELECT Full_Name, COALESCE(Standard_Name,Full_Name) FROM Personals LEFT JOIN Standards where Standard_Name=Full_Name`. You'll have to test the query though, because different databases have different functions and even when the names are the same, there may be differences.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; you'll need to [edit] the question to (re)add the correct tag for the product you are really using.

Comment: Please check the expected result table, The string replacement is happening there. For example, 'AJ International' is changing into 'AJ INTL' as in Standrd_name 'International' standrd_name is 'INTL'.

Comment: This is word replacement, which is *not* T-SQL's forté; I can't talk for Snowflake. The solution you need is likely *entirely* different depending on the product, but you have *still* not clarified that.

Comment: @ThomA, I need the solution for SQL server and snowflake. Need to impliment in both products.

Comment: Then I suggest you ask about one, and then *you* can translate a solution for the other. If you are struggling to translate, then you can ask a *new* question, demonstrating your attempts, and explaining what isn't working or what the difficulty you are having is.

Comment: Can multiple words occur per row that needs replacements? nested replace will need a recursive cte most likely which affects performance badly

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this by initially dividing the **fullName** into several rows, ensuring each substring retains its original position in the **fullName** using [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) . Subsequently, we can perform a `left join` with the **Standrd_name** table to obtain the **Standard_name** for each substring.

```
SELECT fullName, STRING_AGG (Name, ' ' ) 
                 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ordinal ) AS [Standard full name]
FROM (
  SELECT fullName, COALESCE(s.Standard_name, p.Name) as Name, ordinal
  FROM (
    SELECT fullName, value as Name, ordinal
    FROM Personal_details
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(fullName, ' ', 1)
  ) AS p
  LEFT JOIN Standrd_name s ON s.Name = p.Name
) AS t
GROUP BY fullName;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ONllNi6S)

---

If there are long name in *standard_name* table. Example:

```
Name                            Standard_name
Limited Liability Corporation   LLC
professional corporation        PC
```

Then try this :

```
SELECT fullName, STRING_AGG (Name, ' ' ) 
                 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ordinal ) AS [Standard full name]
FROM (
  SELECT fullName, COALESCE(s.Standard_name, p.Name) as Name, MIN(ordinal) ordinal
  FROM (
    SELECT fullName, value as Name, ordinal
    FROM Personal_details
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(fullName, ' ', 1)
  ) AS p
  LEFT JOIN Standrd_name s ON s.Name = p.Name OR p.fullName = s.Name
  GROUP BY fullName, COALESCE(s.Standard_name, p.Name)
) AS t
GROUP BY fullName
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/iF0O-F_W)

> This solution is working on SQL Server 2022+

Comment: but there is a possibility of having long name in standard_name table. Example: Limited Liability Corporation to LLC or professional corporation to PC

Comment: Can you check my recent update ?

Comment: sorry for late reply. its working with this perticular set of input. But if I change the input a bit its not working. for example if full name is Tenessy Limited liability corporation.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with python UDF. Below is sample code to do that. You need to update the python code to read the data from standard_table and loop through.

This is only for snowflake

```
create or replace function replace_standard_name(name varchar)
returns varchar
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
handler = 'replace_standard_name'
as 
$$
import re
def replace_standard_name(name):
    standard_names = {'Court':'CT','International':'INTL'}
    for full_name in standard_names:
        pattern = r"\b" + full_name + r"\b"
        name = re.sub(pattern, standard_names[full_name], name)
    return name

$$;

select *,replace_standard_name(full_name) from personal_details;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select full_name , isnull(b.Standard_name, a.full_name) Standard_full_name 
from Personal_details a left join Standrd_name b on a.full_name = b.Name
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**